# Fast interpolation of the values on two parallel planes in 3d space

Tags: python, arrays, interpolation, linear-interpolation, plane

I have sparsely sampled slices of data which are aligned to a 3d volume (medical imaging volume). The slices are all parallel planes to one another. I want to perform a linear interpolation of the values between the planes however using existing solutions like scipy's LinearNDInterpolator are too slow given the size of my volume. I also can not treat my data like a regular grid since the data on the slice (a brain) only takes up a portion of the image (the rest being empty space). The values outside the brain are masked to deal with this but this then makes the data no longer a regular grid.

Is there a solution which would specifically take advantage of the fact that my slices are all parallel? is there any way of leveraging this fact to perform a faster interpolation?

Comment: Do you mean you have two images which are parallel slices, and you want to produce another image that is an interpolation between the two?  That's not a hard problem.  What data, exactly, do you have for each plane?

Comment: Yeah that’s essentially it. The data specifically are histological mouse brain sections anchored to a volume. I can create an average of the two images as the midpoint between the two however this is effectively a one dimensional interpolation. Ideally I would like to do a 3d interpolation to determine the sections between the slices

Comment: But a 3D interpolation is just a series of simple 2D interpolations, right?  It's just a bunch of linear interpolations between the individual pixels.

Comment: If you add some sample data and code (such as showing how scipy's LinearNDInterpolator worked) I would glad to take a look at this. Without any basis for what the data looks like its hard to tell what the solution should look like.